# Covering parts of a background image while other parts are transparent using CSS and HTML only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap (ver 2.3.1) to build a website and I am trying to achieve the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2916/

On that website, I am using a large image as a background to a `<section>` which streches from the left edge of the screen to the right edge (all the way across).

I would like to place a pagination element on top of that image. With the navigation elements themselves being transparent (so the image below can shine throught) and the space left and right to the pagination element to be set in white color or page background color (it should cover the image, thats all).

I've given the pagination elements transparency:

```
.pagination li a, .pagination li span {
    background: transparent;
}
```

I simply do not know how to get the white spaces around the pagination.

Can anyone help me out on this, please?!

Comment: It seems that it is impossible to achieve the desired effect using just CSS and HTML while retaining the responsiveness (image scretch, scale). So I've ended up hacking the solution in JS, using two absolutely positioned cover-DIVs to the left and right of the pagination... Thanks for looking into this guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
.pull-right { position: relative; top: 2em; background: #ccc }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2917/

Something like this?

Comment: hey j__m, thanks for your help! hm, well, sort of - more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2918/ but what I am missing is a "white cover" to the left of "Page" and to the right of ">". Any idea how to cover the "bottom row" of the image?

Comment: getting closer, but this is not the real deal (just to demonstrate what I would like to achieve): http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2921/

Comment: it's not going to work like that.  your div.container has a fixed width and nothing contained within it is going to expand to cover the width of the parent <section>.  your options are change "bootstrap.css", use "position: relative" like i did, or move the pagination controls into a separate element as you did in your "this is how i want it to look" example.

Comment: thank you j__m for the confirmation - I thought it is not going to work but had hoped for a solution. I will use JS to place, strecht and align my pagination as desired! thanks again